# webpack.config + nuxt.config,js

Tags: vue.js, webpack, configuration, nuxt.js

I am new to nuxt.
I want to add following webpack config (from docs for ckeditor vue) to nuxt.js.config
https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/installation/getting-started/frameworks/vuejs-v2.html

```js
const path = require( 'path' );
const CKEditorWebpackPlugin = require( '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-dev-webpack-plugin' );
const { styles } = require( '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-dev-utils' );

module.exports = {
    // The source of CKEditor is encapsulated in ES6 modules. By default, the code
    // from the node_modules directory is not transpiled, so you must explicitly tell
    // the CLI tools to transpile JavaScript files in all ckeditor5-* modules.
    transpileDependencies: [
        /ckeditor5-[^/\\]+[/\\]src[/\\].+\.js$/,
    ],

    configureWebpack: {
        plugins: [
            // CKEditor needs its own plugin to be built using webpack.
            new CKEditorWebpackPlugin( {
                // See https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/features/ui-language.html
                language: 'en',

                // Append translations to the file matching the `app` name.
                translationsOutputFile: /app/
            } )
        ]
    },

    // Vue CLI would normally use its own loader to load .svg and .css files, however:
    //  1. The icons used by CKEditor must be loaded using raw-loader,
    //  2. The CSS used by CKEditor must be transpiled using PostCSS to load properly.
    chainWebpack: config => {
        // (1.) To handle editor icons, get the default rule for *.svg files first:
        const svgRule = config.module.rule( 'svg' );

        // Then you can either:
        //
        // * clear all loaders for existing 'svg' rule:
        //
        //    svgRule.uses.clear();
        //
        // * or exclude ckeditor directory from node_modules:
        svgRule.exclude.add( path.join( __dirname, 'node_modules', '@ckeditor' ) );

        // Add an entry for *.svg files belonging to CKEditor. You can either:
        //
        // * modify the existing 'svg' rule:
        //
        //    svgRule.use( 'raw-loader' ).loader( 'raw-loader' );
        //
        // * or add a new one:
        config.module
            .rule( 'cke-svg' )
            .test( /ckeditor5-[^/\\]+[/\\]theme[/\\]icons[/\\][^/\\]+\.svg$/ )
            .use( 'raw-loader' )
            .loader( 'raw-loader' );

        // (2.) Transpile the .css files imported by the editor using PostCSS.
        // Make sure only the CSS belonging to ckeditor5-* packages is processed this way.
        config.module
            .rule( 'cke-css' )
            .test( /ckeditor5-[^/\\]+[/\\].+\.css$/ )
            .use( 'postcss-loader' )
            .loader( 'postcss-loader' )
            .tap( () => {
                return {
                    postcssOptions: styles.getPostCssConfig( {
                        themeImporter: {
                            themePath: require.resolve( '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-theme-lark' )
                        },
                        minify: true
                    } )
                };
            } );
    }
};
```

My nuxt config is simply current, i did add some modules like axios,boostrap vue and auth to it.

```js
export default {
  // Disable server-side rendering: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/ssr-mode
  ssr: false,

  // Target: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-target
  target: "static",

  // Global page headers: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-head
  head: {
    title: "spa",
    htmlAttrs: {
      lang: "en",
    },
    meta: [
      { charset: "utf-8" },
      { name: "viewport", content: "width=device-width, initial-scale=1" },
      { hid: "description", name: "description", content: "" },
      { name: "format-detection", content: "telephone=no" },
    ],
    link: [{ rel: "icon", type: "image/x-icon", href: "/favicon.ico" }],
  },

  // Global CSS: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-css
  css: ["~/assets/less/colors.less"],

  // Plugins to run before rendering page: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-plugins
  plugins: [],

  // Auto import components: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-components
  components: true,

  // Modules for dev and build (recommended): https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-modules
  buildModules: [],

  // Modules: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-modules
  modules: [
    // https://go.nuxtjs.dev/bootstrap
    "bootstrap-vue/nuxt",
    "@nuxtjs/axios",
    "@nuxtjs/auth-next",

  ],

  auth: {
    redirect: {
      login: "/login",
      logout: "/login",
      callback: false,
      home: "/",
    },
    strategies: {
      laravelSanctum: {
        provider: "laravel/sanctum",
        url: "http://localhost",
        user: {
          property: false, // <--- Default "user"
          autoFetch: true,
        },
        // endpoints: {
        //   login: { url: "api/login", method: "post" },
        //   logout: { url: "api/auth/logout", method: "post" },
        //   user: { url: "api/user", method: "get" },
        // },
      },
    },
  },

  axios: {
    credentials: true,
    baseURL: "http://localhost", // Used as fallback if no runtime config is provided
    // withCredentials: true,
    headers: {
      accept: "application/json",
      common: {
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": true,
      },
      delete: {},
      get: {},
      head: {},
      post: {},
      put: {},
      patch: {},
    },
  },

  // Build Configuration: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-build
  build: {},
  router: {
    middleware: ["auth"],
  },
};
```

And if config like that can be combine with webpack config for ckeditor , is that right way to do so ?
Or should i separate this and build in another direcrory with another sepparate webpack config?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you're looking for that one: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/configuration-glossary/configuration-build#extend

Could create an external config and import it into this object or directly do that inline as most people do.

There are quite some answers on Stackoverflow anyway on how to achieve specific parts of the configuration, feel free to give it a search to find out what you need.